# i want to get the sorted result from elastic search based on discount

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

Hi i want to get the sorted result from elastic based on the calculation on 2 fields , i want to sort based on discount . There is no discount field,i want to calculate it based  on two fields,price and saleprice.Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Script sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) like

```
"sort" : {
    "_script" : {
        "type" : "number",
        "script" : {
            "inline": "doc['price'].value - doc['saleprice'].value",

        },
        "order" : "asc"
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse Failure [_script sorting requires setting the script to sort by]]; }]"
"status": 400
}